# NIFI queue is full and the processor is running but not executing its function

Tags: java, oracle, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-nifi

I'm building an ETL that first gets the date from the cache to use in the query to pull from a database, transform the content, and send it to the microservice API.

I have a problem, when I start all the processor, it works fine, but like 40 hours later, the processors stop working, but they are still on, and the queue starts to fill up.

This is my flow to extract data:
[image]
[image]

And this is my system to update the date:
[image]

I tried restart system and this repeats again.

I want this system to always work

Comment: You have zero-size input flowfiles (queue size in bytes shown as zero), and back pressure was triggered by the object count. Increase Back pressure Object threshold or filter out empty flow files depending on the producer and your business logic

Comment: it means executesql much slower then previous processors. maybe you should trigger "generateflowfile" not so often. or give more threads to executesql...

Comment: The generateflowfile is every 60 seconds and the average per request to the database is 1 or 2 s, and the queue size is zero because it only contains attributes.
I don't know if it's because of load balancing or for all nodes or primary node per processor.